# Get n oldest rows, but no more than x that have the same value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `food` varchar(250) NOT NULL
);
```

With the following data

```
INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `food`) VALUES
(1, 'apple'),
(2, 'apple'),
(3, 'apple'),
(4, 'apple'),
(5, 'apple'),
(6, 'apple'),
(7, 'apple'),
(8, 'banana'),
(9, 'banana'),
(10, 'potato'),
(11, 'potato'),
(12, 'potato'),
(13, 'banana'),
(14, 'banana'),
(15, 'banana');
```

I want to get the oldest 10 rows

```
SELECT *
FROM example
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

**But** I don't want to get more than 5 rows where `food` has the same value.

My current query receives 7 apple (more than I want), 2 banana, and 1 potato. In the data provided, I'd want to receive 5 apple, 2 banana, and 3 potato.

How can I accomplish this?

**Update:**

[SQL Group BY, Top N Items for each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228273/sql-group-by-top-n-items-for-each-group) is not a duplicate because it involves a different database. In particular, `GROUP BY` works different in sql-server than it does in MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Group BY, Top N Items for each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228273/sql-group-by-top-n-items-for-each-group)

Comment: @NendoTaka that's sql-server, this is MySQL. Answers may be different, especially because `GROUP BY` works very different in MySQL than how it works in sql-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a count (in reverse) for each food . . . using variables or a correlated subquery.  This will use the latter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from example t2 where t2.food = t.food and t2.id >= t.id) as seqnum
      from example  t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5
order by id desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: I made an edit so the query would run with the table name provided in the question. Also, `order by id desc` should be `order by id asc`. When I made these changes, I get the expected results!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't create the table and test this, but it should give you what you want. Just a different approach than the one above.

```
Select * 
From (Select ID, Food
, Count(Food) Over(Partition By Food Order by ID) as Appearances 
From Your_Table) as a
Where a.Appearances <= 5
Order By ID Asc
```

You can obviously put the limit if you want.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting for you. There's a button to format selected code you can use, or you can use backticks or 4 spaces.

Comment: This code gives syntax error at `'(Partition By Food Order by ID)`.

Comment: Strange I just tested it on a table I already have just changing column names and it worked. Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Perhaps the Database or MySQL version. I have MySQL 5.5.57.

Comment: My mistake, this works on SQL Server I'm not familiar with differences between that and MySQL.  I'm guessing that's the reason why.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 will support window functions read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html )