# SQL GROUP BY INNER JOIN AND COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, inner-join

I am new to MySQL. I am facing an issue in generating a query.

So Basically I have two tables: device_master_data, device_logs.

device_master_data:

| device_id | device_seral_number |
| --- | --- |

for any device_id there is a unique device_serial_number.

device_logs:

| device_id | log_date | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

so in this table there are multiples entries for a device_id.

for example:
there are 5 entries for a device_id 1, 10 entries for device_id 2

Goal:
To get the TOP 20 most occuring device_id from the device_logs table
and then get the device_serial_number corresponding to the device_id.

Result:

| count | device_serial_number |
| --- | --- |

Please anyone can help it would be really helpful

Comment: What have you tried so far? SQL statement please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Group BY, Top N Items for each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228273/sql-group-by-top-n-items-for-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
SELECT COUNT(dl.device_id) as count, dmd.device_serial_number
   FROM device_logs dl JOIN 
        device_master_data dmd 
        ON dl.device_id = dmd.device_id
GROUP BY d1.device_serial_number
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you intended `device_serial_number` in the `GROUP BY`.  In any case, the `update` makes the answer correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the group by as follows:

```
Select m.device_id, m.device_serial_number, count(*) as cnt
  From device_master_data m join device_logs l on l.device_id = m.device_id
Group by m.device_id, m.device_serial_number
Order by count(*) desc
Limit 20
```