# Get user who has most opened locations

Tags: sql

Table name: **Locations**

```
PlayerID openedLocations
1        Auberdine
1        Feathermoon Stronghold
3        Auberdine
2        Kharanos
4        Kharanos
5        Feathermoon Stronghold
3        Dolanaar
3        Goldshire
```

I tried to get PlayerdID with most quantity of opened locations with next query but it dsnt work at all:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PlayerID
FROM Locations
WHERE count(openedLocations)
SORT BY count(openedLocations)
```

Comment: use `group by` and order by `count` desc then `top 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Group BY, Top N Items for each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228273/sql-group-by-top-n-items-for-each-group)

Comment: nope, anyways counts dsnt work I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: it won't work if you don't fix your sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery or common table expression to count the opened locations, then use another select statement to get the playerid with the maximum opened location.

```
WITH LocationCount AS (
SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(OpenedLocations) AS Num_Count
FROM Locations
GROUP BY PlayerID
)
SELECT t1.PlayerID
FROM LocationCount t1
WHERE t1.Num_Count = (SELECT MAX(t2.Num_Count) AS Max_Count
                      FROM LocationCount t2)
;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a457aa8ae5a39a22f9a1552c99a35f0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a COUNT and GROUP BY as suggested by RoMEoMusTDiE.

E.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 PlayerID, openedLocations, COUNT(openedLocations)
FROM Locations
GROUP BY PlayerID, openedLocations
```

Comment: I tried the query is suceffully runing but im not getting playerids that have most quantity of opened locations or records in this table :(

Comment: @miki95 Try "SELECT DISTINCT PlayerID...." instead ??