# SQL aggregate sum across three tables (show top for year)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

Employee-> EmpID, Department

Trip-> TripID, EmpID, StartDate

ActualCosts-> TripID, Amount

How do I get this results using SQL (I'm using Query design, Access 2016)

| Year([StartDate]) | Department | SumOfActualCosts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | HR | 6000 |
| 2011 | Prod | 8000 |

Where [Department] will be the Top spender for the Year
e.g. in 2010, HR 6000, Prod 5000, so will select HR to display as the result

This is what I've written so far but it does not reflect the result I want yet (it shows only for one year when I want for all years.

```
SELECT 
    TOP 5 Format$([Trip].[StartDate],'yyyy') AS [StartDate By Year], Employee.GroupTitle, Sum(ActualCosts.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount]
FROM 
    Employee, Trip, ActualCosts 
WHERE 
    Employee.EmpID=Trip.EmpID AND Trip.TripID=ActualCosts.TripID
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Trip].[StartDate],'yyyy'), Employee.GroupTitle
HAVING 
    (((Format$([Trip].[StartDate],'yyyy'))=2019))
ORDER BY 
    Sum(ActualCosts.Amount) DESC;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi - your employee table has empid twice and your trip table doesn’t have empid even though you reference it in your SQL

Comment: Assume second EmpID should have been under Trip table. Use Access query designer to generate correct SQL syntax with JOIN clauses. This is really basic SQL construction.

Comment: However, if you want the TOP 1 per year, that is complicated. Does this answer your question? [SQL Group BY, Top N Items for each Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228273/sql-group-by-top-n-items-for-each-group)